# $f(x)=\sin(\frac{π}4(x-[x]))$ if $[x]$ is odd, $x≥0$, and $\cos(\fracπ4(1-x+[x])$ if $[x]$ is even and $x≥0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

> **QUESTION:** Consider the function $f(x)=\sin(\frac{π}4(x-[x]))$ if $[x]$ is odd, $x≥0$, and $\cos(\fracπ4(1-x+[x])$ if $[x]$ is even and $x≥0$. Where, $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer function less than or equal to $x$.
>
> $i)$ Sketch the graph of the function on a plain paper.
>
> $ii)$ Determine the points of discontinuity of $f$ and the points where it is not differentiable.

**MY APPROACH:** I changed $(x-[x])$ to $\{x\}$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.
$\because$ $\{x\}$ belongs to $(0,1)$ $\therefore$ $\sin(\fracπ4\{x\})$ belongs to $(0,\frac1{√2})$ when $[x]$ is odd. Likewise I did for the cosine part. But this does not seem to be of much use.

Can someone help me out?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of interest is $$f(x) =\begin{cases} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}f \right), \  \space \text{if} \ 2n+1 \le x\lt 2n+2  \hspace{1.5 cm} n\in \mathbb N\cup \{0\} \\  \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{4}(1+f) \right), \ \space \text{if} \ 2n\le x\lt2n+1 \end{cases} $$ where $f$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Notice that determining the graph for $0\le x \le 2$ will suffice, as the function only depends on $f$.

In $[0,1)$, $f(x)$ increases from $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ to $1$. In $[1,2)$, $f(x)$ increases from $0$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$. We have a point of discontinuity at $x=1$, and consequently at all odd integers.

The only thing that remains to do is to check whether $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=2$. Note the left derivative is $$\lim_{x\to 2^-} \frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2} \\ =\lim_{x\to 2^-}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}(x-1)\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}{x-2} \\ =\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt 2}$$

The right derivative, similarly is $\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt 2}$. Hence, $f(x)$ is differentiable at $2$ and consequently at all even numbers. Now you should be able to draw out the graph.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Can you please include the graph too so that I may know that my answer is right..

Comment: @StrangerForever I don’t think I have a software to graph piecesie functions. You can try graphing the two functions separately on Wolfram or Desmos.

Comment: I tried Desmos.. but I couldn't write the conditions well..